# array.splice() is not working properly in mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**I am using splice along with findOne() to remove an nested element  .**

*This is my JSON data*

```
     "username" : "xyz",
    "ProductInCart" : [
            {
                    "id" : ObjectId("5a533a0a6a0207023b8e30d3"),
                    "ProductImage" :"",
                    "Title" : "Model Green",
                    "Price" : 399,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5a53667774d601028b9cb43f")
            },
            {
                    "id" : ObjectId("5a533a0a6a0207023b8e30d3"),
                    "ProductImage" :"",
                    "Title" : "Model Green",
                    "Price" : 399,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5a53667b74d601028b9cb440")
            }
```

**this is my delete route**

```
    router.delete('/cart/remove/:ordername/:id',function(req,res){

 var ProductId = req.params.id;
 var OrderName = req.params.ordername; 

User.findOne({id:req.user._id},function(err,user){
if (err) {
throw err;
} else {  
  user.ProductInCart[OrderName].splice(ProductId,1);
  user.save();
  res.redirect("back");
}
})       
})
```

**This is returning following error in command line**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ProductInCart' of null

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: Looks like the `user` parameter is null, but there wasn't any error thrown either. Are you sure a record exists that matches your query? Perhaps there is no user with the ID you were given?

Comment: I changed my code to "User.findById(req.user._id,function(err,user){"  and now im getting err :" TypeError: Cannot call method 'splice' of undefined",        I really don't know what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving the error because the position being referenced prior to splice is undefined. "user.ProductInCart[OrderName]" being passed in is not a valid reference to any of the objects in the ProductsInCart array.

The code is looking at the position with the value being passed as OrderName on the ProductCart property. My assumption from reading your code is that you would be passing in a product name, rather than an array position as OrderName. If this is the case, you will need to search through the ProductsInCart array to find the correct position before using splice.

As a general note, it's good to perform null checks prior to referencing nested properties - consider the code below in this situation.

```
if (user.ProductInCart && user.ProductInCart[OrderName]) {
   user.ProductInCart[OrderName].splice(ProductId,1);
   user.save();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here its alternative solution( without using .splice())

```
   router.delete('/cart/remove/:ordername/:id',function(req,res){

     User.update({_id:req.user._id},{ $pull:{ProductInCart:
         {_id:req.params.id}}},function(err,deleted){
               if (err) {
                console.log(err)
               } else {
      res.redirect("back");
      }
    })  
  })
```